# Is there an equivalent of getch() function in Mac?

Tags: c, macos, getch

I am not able to find the equivalent header file for **conio.h** (for C programs) **in Mac**.

I was wondering if there is any option for **getch() function in Mac**?

I want to use it such that user can give options and program will go forward without pressing enter.

Comment: There is no universal solution, the easiest is probably to use ncurses or one of the other suggestions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to look at ncurses. It has a lot in common with conio. You can get its documentation with "man ncurses".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried with ncurses but its giving me following error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_stdscr", referenced from:
      _main in test-54aaa4.o
  "_wgetch", referenced from:
      _main in test-54aaa4.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Are you linking libncurses? You can't just include the header and not link the library.

Comment: Thanks rob. It's working fine now. I was not linking ncurses. I used -lncurses to link the library and now it's working without a hitch. 